# Removing WordPress wrapper div when container => false fails

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having troubles removing the WordPress wrapper div from my `wp_nav_menu()`. I've passed `container => false` to my menu args but the div keeps displaying.
I'm using the following arguments:

```
$defaults = array(
   'container' => false,
   'theme_location' => 'menu',
   'menu_class' => 'main-nav',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

I have also declared the menu in my `functions.php` file.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
   'main-nav' => __( 'Main Nav', 'ldsshop' ),
));
```

I have used these arguments with previous themes with no problems, but in this instance the wrapper keeps displaying, and I'm at a point where I need some extra eyes and help, no doubt I've missed something.

Thanking you all in advance,

Stu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `container` empty like this

```
'container' => '',
```

So it will like this

```
$defaults = array(
   'container' => '',
   'theme_location' => 'menu',
   'menu_class' => 'main-nav',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

It will work, even it's working on my end.

**Update About Solved This Question**

Try to the following using `array` in `wp_nav_menu`

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'menu', 
    'container' => '',
    'menu_class' => 'main-nav'
) );
```

use same `''` about `container` if `false` does not work

Here is [`an article`](http://intavant.com/blog/2012/how-to-remove-the-menu-container-div-in-wordpress/) finding some helpful

See more in the codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Thanks for your help fool-dev, I just tried out the `'container' => ''` to no avail, the wrapper is still displaying. I copied and pasted your code direct as well as clearing my cache and resetting my localhost

Comment: Hey, I don't know why look this http://www.johnbhartley.com/2013/remove-div-and-ul-from-wp_nav_menu/ also this http://intavant.com/blog/2012/how-to-remove-the-menu-container-div-in-wordpress/ I think it would be help

Comment: Hey @StuCowley See the ***Update*** section

Comment: Hey fool-dev, I got it working with the article over at [Intavant](http://intavant.com/blog/2012/how-to-remove-the-menu-container-div-in-wordpress/) I'll add my solution, thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Well Done :) @flying-dev

Answer (score 0):

In my case `"container" => false` doesn't work, It only works when you write  `"items_wrap" => "%3$s"`  but it removes all wraps including `<ul>` if you want to remove `<div>` and have your menu wrapped in `<ul>` I recommend to do this way

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'theme_location'  => 'header_menu',
    'menu'            => 'header_menu',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    'container'       => false,
    'menu_class'      => 'nav',
    'list_item_class' => 'nav-item',
    'link_class'      => 'nav-link',
    'menu_id' => 'menu-main-menu'
));
```